# IEEE ACCESS, \headeretal Issue.. Title is crossing template border

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style, ieeeconf

When I use \markboth{\hederetal} the title is going away from the template border. Please suggest me how to fit title with in IEEE access template within borders as show in attached figures.

```
\documentclass{IEEEaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphics} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{epsfig}   % for postscript graphics files
\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{times}    % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{caption}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                       

\begin{document}
    \history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
    \doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

    \title{Virtual Network Functions: A comprehensive survey and research aspects in designing and implementation
        through ETSI Standard Architecture and Mnanagement Perspective}


    \markboth
    {Shantharama \headeretal: Virtual Network Functions: A comprehensive survey and research aspects in designing and implementation
    through ETSI Standard Architecture and Mnanagement Perspective }
    {Shantharama \headeretal: Virtual Network Functions: A comprehensive survey and research aspects in designing and implementation    through ETSI Standard Architecture and Mnanagement Perspective }

    \begin{abstract}
        These instructions.
    \end{abstract}

    \begin{keywords}
        Virtualized Network Function (VNF), 
        Network Function Virtualization (NFV),
        Container Network Function (CNF),
        NFV Orchestration, 
        Software Defined Networking 
    \end{keywords}

    \titlepgskip=-15pt

    \maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here
\end{abstract}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\EOD
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of *pictures* of your code, provide the code itself. More specifically, please provide us with a minimal working example (or MWE). It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and replicate your current problem. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) Can you do that?

Comment: I have posted the code, let me know if you need more information. 
Thank you for helping me